# How to convert variable to a regex string?

Tags: python, regex

I am working in python I am looping through a large group of strings and I want to be able to see if they are in a second list of strings.

```
for line in dictionary:
    line = line.replace('\r\n','').replace('\n','')
    for each in complex8list:
        txt = re.compile(.*line.*)
        if re.search(each, txt):
```

I need to be able to check if the string with anything before it, and anything after it is in the second list.

What is the correct syntax to do this?

Comment: Please add sample data to your question.

Answer (score 0):

If `line` isn't a regex, you don't even need regex for this.

```
if line in each:
```

If `line` is a regex, then you don't need to do anything since a leading `.*` is implied with `re.search` and a trailing `.*` is unnecessary.

```
if re.search(line, each):
```

BTW you seem to have the arguments to `re.search` backwards.